# "Following" and "favorites" relationship models in Rails---one master model or specific models for each relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model, social-networking, database-normalization

I'm working on an app where a user can have one of two kinds of relationships to other users---either `favoriting` them, or `following` them---and I suppose the reverse actions, `is favorited by` and `is being follow by` will also come up as methods I'll want to call.

What are the considerations I should have in making my user model?  Specifically, should I have one model, relationships, that specifies:

```
Relationships
user_1 | relationship_type | user_2
```

where relationship_type is `favoriting` or `following`?

Or should I have 2 separate models:

```
Favorites
user_1 | user_2

Follows
user_1 | user_2
```

I don't know a whole lot about databases, so can I ask what are the considerations in choosing between these two potential setups?  Is 2 more normalized than 3, or less?  Does that matter?  Under what circumstances?

**UPDATE**

Sorry this just struck me: let's say there's a third relationship, like "reviews"/"reviewed_by"--and the question is about 3, rather than 2 different bidirectional relationship types.  Does increasing the number of relationship types impact this?

```
Favorites
user_1 | user_2

Follows
user_1 | user_2

Reviews
user_1 | user_2
```

Comment: Use better naming to make it simpler to read.  Use something like favoring_user & faveored_by_user.  Use method #1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for 2 different models in one table, that is, use the Single Table Inheritance Pattern.
This way, you get a db table that looks close to your option #1 and have a clean model with two different classes for Favourites and Follows on the Object Model side resulting in clearer code & naming.

As for Naming, Michael Hartl uses "followers" and "followed_users" in his example, which seems quite similar to what you are striving at:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top

Comment: and I was about to say: this also makes for easy extension in case you want to add just another relationship with users and then I saw your update ;-)